# SQL Two tables, need to pull depending on what data is in each

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to do a simple SQL Query (Oracle) that consists of two tables, "Revised" and "Projected".  I would like to always pull records from the "Revised" table, if present.  If the revised table is blank, then I need to pull from the "Projected" table.  The different join combinations I have been trying do not return the data that I am looking for.  Any help is appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: Can we see the queries you've written and the structure of the tables? If either table has a lot of fields, consider just showing the relevant fields.

Comment: Columns include Revised_ProjectID, Revised_Amt, Revised_Date and Projected_ProjectID, Projected_Amt, Projected_Date.  I've tried both suggestions below.  Basically, If there is data on the Revised Table, use that data, if the Revised table is blank, use the Projected Table.  If both tables have data, I need to pull the revised. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried something like this?

```
select your columns 
from revised
union all
select your columns 
from projected where not exists (select 1 from revised);
```

Select all from revised and all from projected if there is nothing in revised.

Or, without `exists`:

```
select your columns 
from revised
union all
select your columns 
from projected where (select count(*) from revised) = 0;
```

**Edit**: to get your requirement at project level, just filter per project:

```
select your columns 
from revised
union all
select your columns 
from projected p where (select count(*) 
                      from revised r
                      where r.Revised_ProjectID = p.Projected_ProjectID) = 0;
```

Comment: Florin, thank you for the response.  This query is only pulling records from the Revised table.  If the Revised table is blank, then nothing is being pulled from the Projected, which is what I am looking for the query to do.

Comment: I don't see how this cannot be what you want. What does return `select count(*) from revised`?

Comment: Also, very important: Did you understood my response/queries?

Comment: Select count returns the total number of rows, as it should.  The other queries do not pull from the Projected table when the Revised table is blank.

Comment: What means "when the Revised table is blank"? For me it means it has no rows.

Comment: I think we're on the right track.  For some reason, when I add the "where (select count(*) from revised) = 0" I am returning zero results from the Projected table.  And yes, "when the revised table is blank" means when it has no rows for that Project_ID.

Comment: "For that project I'd". This is what it is called "you've changed the specification". I will edit the answer tomorrow, now it is night and I am on the phone.

Comment: I added "Revised.Project_ID=Projected.Project_ID" to your syntax and it seems to work out great.  I appreciate your help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use case and a left join to achieve this.

```
 select p.Project_ID,
    case when r.Project_ID is null then p.ProjectedPaymentAmount else r.RevisedPaymentAmount end as PaymentAmount,
    case when r.Project_ID is null then p.ProjectedPaymentDate else r.RevisedPaymentDate end as PaymentDate
from ProjectPayments_Projected p
left join ProjectPayments_Revised r on p.Project_ID = r.Project_ID
```

If a project can have multiple revisions use this.

```
;WITH cte AS
(
  SELECT *,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Project_ID ORDER BY RevisedPaymentDate DESC) AS rn
  FROM ProjectPayments_Revised
)

select p.Project_ID,
    case when r.Project_ID is null then p.ProjectedPaymentAmount else r.RevisedPaymentAmount end as PaymentAmount,
    case when r.Project_ID is null then p.ProjectedPaymentDate else r.RevisedPaymentDate end as PaymentDate
from ProjectPayments_Projected p
left join cte r on r.rn = 1 and r.Project_ID = p.Project_ID
```

Comment: Columns include Revised_ProjectID, Revised_Amt, Revised_Date and Projected_ProjectID, Projected_Amt, Projected_Date.  I am getting an "incorrect syntax near IS and NULL" when I attempt your SQL.

Comment: This returns more data than needed.                                                              There are 3 columns on each table:                                                               R.ID, R.Amt, R.Date & P.ID, P.Amt, P.Date                                                      I need the query to return the correct 3 columns based on whether or not the Revised table has any data in it or not.  If there is data on the Revised table, pull that data.  If not, pull Projected Data.  If both have data, pull Revised.

Comment: I edited my response to select all 3 columns. However I'm not sure I understand what you're asking. If neither of my suggestions work maybe you could provide us with sample Input Data and the Expected Output?

Comment: Please try my second suggestion, I think it is what you are asking for.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.  Looks weird.  Usually works.

```
select id, max(amt) amt, max(date) date
from ( select p.id id, p.amt amt, p.date date
         from projected p
       union
       select r.id, r.amt, r.date
         from revised )
group by id;
```

Comment: Which table should the fields in the Select statement come from?

Comment: SELECT ID, MAX(AMT) AMT,MAX(DATE) DATE
FROM 

(SELECT P.PROJECT_ID, P.AMOUNT,PDATE

FROM Projected

    UNION

SELECT R.PROJECT_ID,R.AMT,R.DATE
FROM REVISED)

GROUP BY ID;                                                                                                        I'm getting "incorrect syntax near 'GROUP'"?

Comment: you have a couple of errors:  you are using AMOUNT (I thought it was amt) and PDATE, not p.date.  Also, you should never name a column with an bare datatype (DATE).  Also, your initial inline view query MUST contain the column name aliases as shown in my original query.  You are also referencing p.id, but your from clause is not aliasing the tables "Projected p".

Comment: select id, max(amt) amt, max(date) date1
from ( select ProjectPayments_Projected.Project_ID id, ProjectPayments_Projected.ProjectedPaymentAmount amt, ProjectPayments_Projected.ProjectedPaymentDate date1
         from ProjectPayments_Projected 
       union
       select ProjectPayments_Revised.Project_ID, ProjectPayments_Revised.RevisedPaymentAmount, ProjectPayments_Revised.RevisedPaymentDate 
         from ProjectPayments_Revised )
group by id

Comment: Here is the actual table/Column names without table aliases, still getting the same error.

Comment: I am going to put these tables up (when I can).  But your select of max(date) from an inline view with the column ProjectedPayment_date date1 is going to fail.  Your aliases have to agree.

Answer (score 0):

So there is always either a `Revised` record, a `Projected` record or both for a project ID. One way is to outer join the tables and see what you get:

```
select
  case when revised_projectid is not null then revised_projectid else projected_projectid end as project_id,
  case when revised_projectid is not null then revised_amt else projected_amt end as project_amt,
  case when revised_projectid is not null then revised_date else projected_date end as project_date
from revised r
full outer join projected p on p.projected_projectid = r.revised_projectid;
```

Just for the fun of it, here is a UNION query getting the same results. We union the two tables, giving them a priority flag on the way. Then we rank the records per project_id, giving the better record rank 1. Then we dismiss the other records and are done. You see there are many ways to solve this problem :-)

```
select project_id, project_amt, project_date
from
(
  select 
    project_id, 
    project_amt, 
    project_date, 
    row_number() over (partition by project_id order by priority) as rn
  from
  (
    select 
      1 as priority, 
      revised_projectid as project_id, 
      revised_amt as project_amt, 
      revised_date as project_date
    from revised
    union all
    select 
      2 as priority,
      projected_projectid as project_id, 
      projected_amt as project_amt, 
      projected_date as project_date
    from projected
  )
)
where rn = 1;
```

I've added this second query to my answer in order to show you another option. And while one approach may be the better this time, maybe the other is the right choice next time you have a similar problem.

Comment: The first query gives me the correct logic, but I am returning duplicate rows of the same value.  Any way to correct that? The second query is giving me a "syntax error near from" message.

Comment: **First query:** Okay, I assumed the Project ID to be unique for the tables. If it is not, then you may get duplicates of course. Use `SELECT DISTINCT` to remove these from your results. Anyway, you could still get multiple result records for one project ID with different values, naturally. **Second query:** I don't get a syntax error (Oracle 11g). Maybe you have a very old Oracle version?